# Webgrid cansort:false formats font of table header mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I have a webgrid in mvc4, where I have set some of the columns non-sortable:

```
....
grid.Column("CreatedDate", "Created Date", canSort: false, style: "columnWidthSmall"),
....
```

The problem is, that when this is set, it will format the font of the column header, just a little bit, but is noticeable. It makes it a bit smaller, and raises the font a bit. It annoys me. The style is not doing anything with the font - the font only changes when I set the `canSort`.

I'm not sure how to prevent this - could not find anything on Google.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the style of the header in WebGrid with `headerStyle` parameter that is a CSS class name.

```
@grid.GetHtml(
        headerStyle: "headerStyle",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Column1", canSort:false),
            grid.Column("Column2")
        )
    )
```

When a column is sortable, WebGrid generates an anchor, otherwise it generates the column name

```
<tr class="headerStyle">
    <th scope="col">Column1</th>
    <th scope="col">
        <a href="/?sort=Column2&sortdir=ASC">Column2<a>
    </th>
</tr>
```

With an appropriate CSS class you can change the appearance of the header; something like this

```
.headerStyle th{
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not mention, but I already have a `headerStyle` set. And as it look right now, it does not help.
And I tried to do something like your last line of code, but it did not help either.

Comment: It seems to me that other CSS style overrides your style, if you use default template in Visual Studio, it has an style for table that might be the reason, you can check it with Firebug in Firefox.

Comment: You were right - thanks! It was a override in another file. (: